# Android Graphics: how to recreate look of Microbes live wallpaper?

Tags: java, android, graphics, 2d, live-wallpaper

Video Example [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7igZ4CyoB-I)

I'm trying to recreate the look of Microbes live wallpaper for Android, developed by Samsung I believe. Graphics programming is not my forte though and I need some help to get started.

Image Example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD7ko.jpg)

I'm assuming I can represent the microbes using sprites.

- **Warping shape**: When microbes are stationary, they are rounder. But, when they move in a direction they become more oval shaped. Do I represent this with multiple sprite states? Additionally, microbes come in different sizes. Can I just scale from one base image?
- **Animation**: Occasionally, the microbes wobble. So this would be transitioning from round to oval shaped sprite and back?
- **Colors**: Do I have a separate sprite for each color type(blue, yellow, red, etc.) or have one base overlay and assign different colors dynamically? Also, sometimes they momentarily glow a little brighter than their base color, which makes me think some dynamic way of assigning colors would be better than static sprites. What is the best way to do it dynamically?
- **Glowing**: What sort of effect is used to give microbes that glowing look? There's a sort of diffuse foggy region around each microbe. Is that part of the sprite itself or are there shaders involved? If shaders, what specific effect is that?

If there is a non-sprite method that is easier or less resource consuming, I'm all ears. I intend to have it as a live wallpaper as well, so the more efficient the better.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same question few months ago, and now I've made [Microb World](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.massiveshare.microbworld). It's a free game available on Google Play based on this live wallpaper.

I've used LibGDX and it's Sprite based. My sprites are white and I change the color  :

It's the easiest way I've found.

The most difficult was to manage their movement, and my version is not the same as the wallpaper. I use [Universal Tween Engine](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine)